# Durandal's define block using require.js with no parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, requirejs, durandal

I need to use a library in my javascript file for one of my pages. I found that I could use:

```
define(["plugins/http", "someLibrary"], function (http, foo) {
    /* code: never using "foo", but using methods from someLibrary */
}
```

Originally, I expected a value for foo, since all the other examples (like http) had values for the parameters, but that apparently isn't how someLibrary works. Having foo as a parameter seemed useless, so I removed it to see if it still worked, and it did.

Is it alright to leave the parameter off? What is the general consensus for Durandal/Require.js best practice in this case? Neither option seems particularly elegant. Is there some better way to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are various libraries that set up behaviors, like bootstrap, and these can be included in the require statement but left off of the function arguments. You can also write the following require.js shorthand:

```
var http = require('plugins/http');
require('somelibrary');

function viewModel() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would only need an assigned variable if the plugin returns a references (like the `plugins\http` case).

Some plugin attaches itself to other objects or plugins, adding functions or properties to other objects, therefore it doesn't return any references (like the `someLibrary` in your example). So you don't need a variable for that.

My personal practices are order the sequence of the plugins in `define(...)` according to whether they need a assigned variable or not, plugins that **do not need variable**, will be define **later**, those that **need variable** will be defined **first**. This is to align with javascript's way of `function` definition where you always put the optional parameters to the right.